# KeyError: 'not found in index' -created dummy variables not found in index

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am working on a logistic regression problem. I created 2 new variables based on information in another column (if a value is above or below a threshold, give value 'gt40'). Then I have to create dummy variables for the 'DIABETES', 'bmi_cat', and 'albumin_cat' variables. That all works fine and I can print a head/export a csv that matches what I need.

Then when I try to actually run a logistic regression model I get the following error:

```
X = new_df[['Age','Sex','SMOKE', 'DIABETES_NO', 'DIABETES_INSULIN', 'DIABETES_NON-INSULIN', 'bmi_cat_gte40',
           'bmi_catlt40','bmi_cat0','albumin_catgt3.5', 'albumin_catlt3.5','ablumin_cat0']]

y = new_df['Mortality']
#Create train, test, split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.3)

#Logistic Regression Model
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Then I get the following errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-88ad326a3d1e> in <module>
      1 #Create X and y
      2 X = new_df[['Age','Sex','SMOKE', 'DIABETES_NO', 'DIABETES_INSULIN', 'DIABETES_NON-INSULIN', 'bmi_cat_gte40',
----> 3            'bmi_catlt40','bmi_cat0','albumin_catgt3.5', 'albumin_catlt3.5','ablumin_cat0']]
      4 
      5 y = new_df['Mortality']

E:\Users\davidwool\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2680         if isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, Index, list)):
   2681             # either boolean or fancy integer index
-> 2682             return self._getitem_array(key)
   2683         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
   2684             return self._getitem_frame(key)

E:\Users\davidwool\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_array(self, key)
   2724             return self._take(indexer, axis=0)
   2725         else:
-> 2726             indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
   2727             return self._take(indexer, axis=1)
   2728 

E:\Users\davidwool\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _convert_to_indexer(self, obj, axis, is_setter)
   1325                 if mask.any():
   1326                     raise KeyError('{mask} not in index'
-> 1327                                    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))
   1328 
   1329                 return com._values_from_object(indexer)

KeyError: "['bmi_catlt40' 'bmi_cat0' 'albumin_catgt3.5' 'albumin_catlt3.5'\n 'ablumin_cat0'] not in index"
```

The csv looks fine and has all of the values, but when I try to run the model, it cannot find those variables I created off the dummies in the index.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
#columns
new_df.columns
```

```
Index(['Age', 'Sex', 'DIABETES', 'bmi', 'SMOKE', 'DPRALBUM', 'Readmission',
       'Infection', 'bmi_cat', 'albumin_cat', 'Optimized', 'Mortality',
       'DIABETES_INSULIN', 'DIABETES_NO', 'DIABETES_NON-INSULIN', 'bmi_cat_0',
       'bmi_cat_gte40', 'bmi_cat_lt40', 'albumin_cat_0', 'albumin_cat_gt3.5',
       'albumin_cat_lt3.5'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: can you add the output off ```new_df.columns```. this is probably a typo in the name of one of the columns

Comment: yes I will add that to the original post now

Answer (score 0):

What You wrote :

```
['Age','Sex','SMOKE', 'DIABETES_NO', 'DIABETES_INSULIN', 'DIABETES_NON-INSULIN', 'bmi_cat_gte40',
    'bmi_catlt40',  'bmi_cat0',  'albumin_catgt3.5',  'albumin_catlt3.5',  'ablumin_cat0']
```

The actual name of the columns you want to get :

```
['Age', 'Sex', 'SMOKE', 'DIABETES_NO', 'DIABETES_INSULIN', 'DIABETES_NON-INSULIN', 'bmi_cat_gte40',
    'bmi_cat_lt40', 'bmi_cat_0', 'albumin_cat_gt3.5', 'albumin_cat_lt3.5', 'albumin_cat_0']
```

Try comparing the second line of each list and you'll see the some differences.

Comment: That did it! Oh my goodness...I spent hours staring at this code trying to figure out what was wrong... That you so much for this, glad it was a simple fix!